# UserControl with a button that can handle multiple actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I want to develop a user control (by inheriting UserControl) which contains a button which when clicked does multiple actions. Those actions should be defined somewhere. So when I sue the control on page1.aspx the button does action X, when its used on page2.aspx and the button is clicked there, action Y is started and so on.

Whats a good way to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you be more precise? Do you need control to know what page it is used on and to decide which onclick handler to call depending on this page properties?

Comment: I need to be able to give the button actions from outside...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the behaviour is very specific to the control type you could do the following

Create an enum

```
public enum MyUserControlAction
{
    FirstAction = 0,
    SecondAction = 1,
    ThirdAction = 2
}
```

then create a public property on your user control

```
public MyUserControlAction Action {get;set;}
```

then in your user controls button click handler

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    switch (this.Action)
    {
        case MyUserControlAction.FirstAction:DoSomething();break;
        case MyUserControlAction.SecondAction:DoSomethingElse();break;
        case MyUserControlAction.ThirdAction:DoSomethingAgain();break;
    }
}
```

then when you add to your form

```
<cc1:MyUserControl runat="server" Action="FirstAction" ID="ctrl1" />
<cc1:MyUserControl runat="server" Action="SecondAction" ID="ctrl2" />
<cc1:MyUserControl runat="server" Action="ThirdAction" ID="ctrl3" />
```

**another solution is to expose the click**

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Click;

protected virtual void OnClick()
{
     if (this.Click !=null)
     {
          this.Click.Invoke(this,EventArgs.Empty);
     }
}
```

then in your button click

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    this.OnClick();
}
```

You can then handle the click from the button as an event on the user control and you can do what you like...

Comment: How do I use this from the aspx which holds the control?

Comment: It isnt really exposing the click, its simply calling another custom Click event that you have defined, this design is fairly standard for asp.net controls.

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating a user control that accepts a "contained" user control that expose a well-known interface:

```
public interface IActionable
{
    void DoButtonAction(object param);
}
```

Then make a separate user control for each page that implements `IActionable`.  All the container has to do is execute `DoButtonAction()` on the contained UserControl when the button is clicked.  Each page's UserControl gets to define what `DoButtonAction()` actually does.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign values to CommandArgument property in each page and then depending on the value you can perform appropriate actions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property to your user control, for example just an int.

Then in the the Button Click event, handle the event differently depending on the value of the property.